# Jquery find method hangs my whole browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery find() makes my whole browser stops working.

The line on which my browser stops working is this one:

```
item.find('div:contains(\'' + myText + '\')').remove();
```

Specifically, the part before the remove(), which is the find() part.

Here are the values of the variables:

```
myText: "Grand sauce ()"

item: e.fn.e.init[1]
    0: a.ui-corner-all ui-state-hover
        item[0].innerText: "Grand sauce...302774"
        item[0].innerHTML: "<table style=" width: 100%; font-size:10px;" name="Grand sauce ()"><tbody><tr><td id="column1" style="width:170px; padding:2px 2px 2px 8px;position: relative;">Grand sauce...302774</td><td style="width:50px; padding:2px;">302774</td><td style="width:70px; padding:2px;">Supp</td><td style="width:70px; padding:2px;"></td><td style="width:50px; padding:2px;">2.00</td><td style="width:80px; padding:2px;">93ml</td><td style="width:90px; padding:2px;"> € 1.35</td></tr></tbody></table>"
```

Why does the browser hangs? The innerHTML isn't that big at all.

Comment: Try `item.find('div:contains('\' + myText + '\')').remove();`

Comment: I don't see any DIV in item. Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: can you tell us what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @roasted If there isn;t a div it shouldn't hang, it should just not do anything.

Comment: @petko_stankoski ya for sure but in this case, why providing code which is not relevant to your issue?

Comment: @roasted But it is relevant. In this case it should not do anything. Instead, it hangs. It doesn't matter what the html is, it shouldn't hang

Comment: @petko_stankoski ha ok, understand what you mean now. But could you provide a jsfiddle or not?

Comment: @petko_stankoski i have found a method to get the section text of active accordion but you deleted the question :/

Answer (score 2):

<del>I think the issue is the `(` and `)` in myText.</del> You can escape it properly or use filter:

```
item.find('div').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text().indexOf(myText) > -1;
}).remove();
```

Try can also try it this way:

```
$('div:contains("' + myText + '")').remove();
```

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/ehuqux/2/edit

Errr, actually, the way you posted works as well. There's just something else up with the code I think.

Comment: Now that you mention it, you're probably right.  I've seen similar issues with accidentally leaving a selector open like `$('a[href=abcd')`.  This was years ago though - I'm surprised it hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: I just messed around a bit and it actually works fine. I think it's just the way it's quoted that might be screwing things up. I'll update my answer. Here's the demo I used: http://jsbin.com/ehuqux/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
item.find('div').filter(function() {
    return ($(this).text().indexOf(myText) != -1);
}).remove();
```

I'm not sure why you're seeing this issue, but I usually try to avoid the more obscure jQuery selectors like `:contains()` because I have had the same issue in the past.